# In eclipse, is there a way to specify a location other than the WEB-INF, for web.xml

Tags: eclipse

I want to place development web.xml in another folder in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the eclipse builder and not ant.
Actually what i did was that i defined web.xml in another folder. So now I have two web.xml, one for welogic with a lot weblogic specific stuff like filters. And i have another for development which i placed in another folder, in the web project and added this folder to the deployment descriptor for tomcat in eclipse. So now when i deploy the application, the web.xml for tomcat which is in my specified folder owerwrites the web.xml present in web-INF folder(in the deployment directory). 
 Looks to me a nice workaround.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the Deployment Assembly properties. Right click on the web project, choose Properties, and then navigate to the Deployment Assembly panel. Remove the /WebContent entry (pointing to /) and then add another entry, of type Folder. It should be rooted where you want to keep the web.xml, and mapped to /.

This technique can be extended to make Eclipse work with arbitrary build tool source layouts.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)
for that purpose. You may define a "conf" directory and place all you config files there, or a resource directory for the same reason.

If haven't use ant for that purpose, I strongly recommend you to do so.

Here is a sample ant build.xml for a web app [Sample Build.XML](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/ant-build-script-for-java-web-application)

I'll use Maven myself, but since you're just beginning, Ant would be just fine.